# JQuery - grab the td value next to radio button

Tags: jquery, html-table, parent, siblings

I have the following dilemma: 
My HTML is as such (this exists within a PL/SQL app.):

```
<table id="search_result_table">
<tr>

<input type=radio name="pv_select" value="'||lv_spriden_id||'"/>
<font face="Calibri" size=3><td id="spriden_id"     name="spriden_id">'||lv_spriden_id||'</td></font>'
<font face="Calibri" size=3><td id="last_name" class="c_last_name"     name="last_name">'||lv_spriden_last_name||'</td></font>
<font face="Calibri" size=3><td id="first_name" class = "c_first_name"     name="first_name">'||lv_spriden_first_name||'</td></font>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am able to get at the selected radio button value via:

```
$("input[name=pv_select]:checked").val()
```

However, I would like to be able to get the value of the "last_name" column cell (which exists within a table next to the radio button). How can I retrieve this value (for the selected row via the radio button) via jQuery?

I've tried several things, but none are working:

```
$("input[name=pv_select]:checked").parent().siblings("td:eq(1)").text());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can post the generated source, because your post doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your html snippet doesn't look like html, what is it?

Comment: The HTML exists within a PL/SQL app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML is invalid; not sure if that’s mucking up your DOM tree, and thus confusing jQuery as it tries to traverse the broken DOM tree.

Here’s valid HTML:

```
<table id="search_result_table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type=radio name="pv_select" value="'||lv_spriden_id||'"/>
        </td>
        <td id="spriden_id" name="spriden_id"><font face="Calibri" size=3>'||lv_spriden_id||'</font></td>
        <td id="last_name" class="c_last_name" name="last_name"><font face="Calibri" size=3>'||lv_spriden_last_name||'</font></td>
        <td id="first_name" class = "c_first_name" name="first_name"><font face="Calibri" size=3>'||lv_spriden_first_name||'</font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And jQuery to get the value of the “last name” table cell in the same row as the checked radio button:

```
$("input[name=pv_select]:checked").parent().siblings("td.c_last_name").text());
```

(I say the HTML is valid: values for the `id` attribute are meant to be unique within an HTML page, so if you have multiple rows using the same id attributes for the table cells, that’s invalid too.)

Comment: Thanks! Fixing the HTML as suggested above solved the issue. This now works in both IE & Firefox. I didn't like referencing the item of interest via eq(). Referencing it via the class name (c_last_name) now works properly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You selector works on a generic table with an **input** in **td** and last name text in another **td**

maybe your problem is that last name is declared after the submit, so you should try to modify the selector with

```
$("input[name=pv_select]:checked").parent().siblings("td:eq(0)").text();
```

where I just changed index of sibling (if I got your table dump correct, your .siblings("td:eq(1)") is First Name, **eq(0) should be last name**)

Just a suggestion..

**EDIT**

When you posted your html excerpt, I realized, that you don't need to check sibling elements of radio's parent. As its parent is **tr** and siblings of **tr** in table are just another table rows.

What you may consider is using traversing function **.next()** which moves to next element in the DOM

It's sad, that I cannot test this enough in FF (or just because Firebug / jquery ext.), but this is the code, you exactly asked for (get next element of radio input):

```
$('input[name="pv_select"]:checked').next();
```

the only problem is, that next element is **font** element, which I cannot seem to render properly in FF (and doesn't reside in the table row - it displays directly inside **body** in FireBug inspector), so **.children()** cannot find  or whatewer td you are trying to find

Comment: No - this doesn't work either. Regardless, I am not able to post the First Name nor the Last Name. I guess to better phrase my question (without getting into the unnecessary details): How can one via JQUERY grab the column cell next to the selected radio button? I.e., let's say we have: <BR>[radio button1] Column1_Value Column2_Value <BR>[radio button2] Column1_Value Column2_Value <BR>[checked radio button3] Column1_Value Column2_Value <Br>How can I grab the Column2_Value value of the *checked* (selected) radio button? (Note that all of the above is included within a table).

Comment: Meant to say: of the selected row (via the radio button). Once again, I am able to grab the radio button value.  Yet cannot grab the value of any of the cells next to the selected radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this works in Firefox, yet not in IE. Hence, I shall be analyzing what may be causing for this to fail in one browser and not the other.